# Is something wrong with my SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT * FROM iveflownthat.messages WHERE from=1 OR to=1
```

Its keeps giving me errors. I checked to make sure that the fields, table, and database name are correct.

Comment: What errors do you get? Did you try using double quotes, i.e. `"from"`?

Comment: If you have an error then include the error message in your question.  Otherwise your question will be down voted and closed.

Answer (score 6):

`FROM` and `TO` are keywords. You should use them like this: `[FROM]`, `[TO]`

```
SELECT * FROM iveflownthat.messages WHERE [from]=1 OR [to]=1
```

Comment: `TO` also is a keyword in `SQL-Server': http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx

Comment: Oh didn't notice it was tagged as sql-server.

Answer (score 0):

You named your column 'from' which is a reserved word, so you're getting this error due to bad syntax.

Answer (score 0):

"from" is a keyword in SQL. ENclose it in square brackets... " WHERE [from] = 1 OR [to] = 1 "

edit" What Alireza said...